# MediatR behavior pipeline order

Tags: .net-core, architecture, mediatr

So I recently started using MediatR and in my project I have several Behaviors set up to run after handling certain type of commands. I add them by registering them as services, like:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(BehaviorOne<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(BehaviorTwo<,>));
```

I looked it up and found that the order, in which behaviors are executed is defined solely by the order of these service registrations. This works fine, but seems very unintuitive and kind of unsafe even.
Are there a way to strictly specify the order that I missed, or is it intended like this?